# SimpleXML XMLIterator fails on encountering empty nodes

Tags: php, simplexml

I'm attempting to use SimpleXML to read an XML File into in array, however the moment the script encounters an empty node (such as <NodeName />) it throws an error saying the XML is 'invalid' and quits.

The XML in question is entirely valid - I would search/replace through the entire thing and remove the empty nodes, but it's far too large to do this efficiently.

The following is a facsimile of the code I am using, how can this be re-factored to ignore, or simply return a null value to the array when it encounters an empty element?

```
$iter = 0;

$xmlIterator = new SimpleXMLIterator($url, 0, true);
for( $xmlIterator->rewind(); $xmlIterator->valid(); $xmlIterator->next() ) {
    $rows[$iter] = array();
    foreach($xmlIterator->getChildren() as $column => $data) {
        $rows[$iter][$column] = $data;

        $data = null;
    }
    $iter++;
}
```

Comment: Can you provide some sample XML as well?  What PHP version?  What libxml version?

Comment: What is the exact error you are getting? It seems odd to me that the parser would be saying the XML was invalid only part way through the loop.